# ExtJS Uncaught Type Error - need a simple solution re. a workaround for known issue

Tags: extjs, extjs4, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

Seems to be a problem adding a component to a viewport in extjs due to some known issue
The ideal would be:

```
var paneltab = Ext.create('ROMLProjectAdmin.view.MainTabPanel');
Ext.getCmp('loginregister').destroy();
Ext.Viewport.add(paneltab);
```

An error occurs:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function constructor(){
  // Opera has some problems returning from a constructor when Dragonfly isn't running. The || null seems to
  // be sufficient to stop in misbehaving. Known to be required against 10.53, 11.51 and 11.61.
  return this.constructor.apply(this, arguments) || null;
} has no method 'add'
```

[Found this on the web](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?254515-Controller-View-Getter-Question) which explains what's going on but I don't fully understand how to implement the proposed solution using 'refs' as I'm a newbie. I wondered if someone could give me a simpler explanation.

Or, based on the failing code above, can someone please give me an alternative way to launch a tab panel (in this case user logged in and so that screen is done with and now to open the main tabs).

Thanks in advance.

Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Ext.Viewport`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.container.Viewport) is just the **class**, you need an **instance** of that class in order to add components to it:

```
Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
    id: 'myviewport'
});

var paneltab = Ext.create('ROMLProjectAdmin.view.MainTabPanel');
Ext.getCmp('loginregister').destroy();
Ext.getCmp('myviewport').add(paneltab);
```